# All Laravel routes exposed. How to move it to app.js or minify if possible

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I am using Ziggy for my Laravel, Vue.js and Inertia js project. In the view page source, I can clearly see all of the Laravel routes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const Ziggy = {"url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8787","port":8787,"defaults":{},"routes": 
    ......

"sup_finish_tt_order":{"uri":"front\/finishorder","methods":["POST"]},"assign__tt":{"uri":"front\/assigntt","methods":["POST"]},"technicians":{"uri":"technicians","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"change-password":{"uri":"change-password","methods":["GET","HEAD"]},"reset.password":{"uri":"c
----------
</script>
```

Is there any way to relocate this Ziggy object in app.js or make it less obvious? Based on the [Ziggy](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy) documentation and the answer attempted here I try importing it in app.js,a but it's not working.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
> at Object.inherits (app.js:124712)
> at Object. (app.js:68991)
> at Object../node_modules/irc/lib/irc.js (app.js:69342)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:64)
> at Object../node_modules/ziggy/index.js (app.js:140181)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:64)
> at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:141504)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:64)
> at Object.0 (app.js:142081)
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:64)

**___________________________Set up ______________________________________**

//Backend

```
$ php artisan ziggy:generate
File generated!
```

//  sample /resources/js/ziggy.js file

```
const Ziggy = {"url":"http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8787","port":8787,"defaults":{},"routes":{"debugbar.openhandler":{"uri":"_debugbar\/open"  /*..... All named routes as expeted */


if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && typeof window.Ziggy !== 'undefined') {
    for (let name in window.Ziggy.routes) {
        Ziggy.routes[name] = window.Ziggy.routes[name];
    }
}

export { Ziggy };
```

// /resources/js/app.js

```
require('./bootstrap')
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueMeta from 'vue-meta'
import PortalVue from 'portal-vue'
import { App, plugin } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue'
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress/src'

// Ziggy start here
import route from 'ziggy';
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute, config = Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config),
    },
});
// ziggy end here



import { BootstrapVue, IconsPlugin } from 'bootstrap-vue'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)
Vue.use(IconsPlugin)
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
import { mixins } from 'vue-chartjs'
import TreeBrowser from './Pages/globalComponents/TreeBrowser.vue'
//Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.mixin({ methods: { route: window.route } })
Vue.use(plugin)
Vue.use(PortalVue)
Vue.use(VueMeta)
Vue.component('TreeBrowser', TreeBrowser)
InertiaProgress.init()

let app = document.getElementById('app')

new Vue({
    metaInfo: {
        titleTemplate: (title) => title ? `${title} - FNV` : 'FNV yours'
    },
    render: h => h(App, {
        props: {
            initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
            resolveComponent: name =>
                import (`./Pages/${name}`).then(module => module.default),
        },
    }),
}).$mount(app)
```

// /webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
        },
    },
});
```

usage of ziggy ex in Login.vue

````
this.$inertia.post(this.route('login.attempt'), data, {
        onStart: () => this.sending = true,
        onFinish: () => this.sending = false,
      })
    ```
````

Comment: may I ask "why"? One way or another your javascript code will have to know the routes so its exposed anyhow

Comment: Yet but they are not at least in the html.

Comment: based on the accepted answers and by removing  ``` Vue.mixin({ methods: { route: window.route } }) ```  it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not using Blade, or would prefer not to use the @routes directive, Ziggy provides an artisan command to output its config and routes to a file: php artisan ziggy:generate

```
import route from 'ziggy';
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';

Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute, config = Ziggy) => route(name, params, absolute, config),
    },
});
```

You can optionally create a webpack alias to make importing Ziggy's core source files easier

```
// webpack.mix.js

// Mix v6
const path = require('path');

mix.alias({
    ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
});

// Mix v5
const path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
        },
    },
});
```

This mean that you should change path here '.ziggy'

```
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';
```

Comment: App does not mounted due to import route from 'ziggy';
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
    at Object.inherits (app.js:124712)
    at Object.<anonymous> (app.js:68991)
    at Object../node_modules/irc/lib/irc.js (app.js:69342)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Object../node_modules/ziggy/index.js (app.js:140181)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Module../resources/js/app.js (app.js:141504)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)
    at Object.0 (app.js:142081)
    at __webpack_require__ (app.js:64)

Comment: Did you changed path at this line?
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';
Or added for webpack alias?

Comment: No ,nothing is changed , i copy the above answer /pee documentation  as it is .

Comment: I changed my answer, please check

Answer (score 9):

Maintainer of Ziggy here. [FightInGlory's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66177021/6484459) is correct.

Run `php artisan ziggy:generate`.

Then, in your `webpack.mix.js` file:

```js
const path = require('path');

// Mix v6
mix.alias({
    ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
});

// Or, Mix v5
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist'),
        },
    },
});
```

Then, in the file that you want to use Ziggy in:

```js
import route from 'ziggy';
// Change './ziggy' to the relative path to the file generated above, usually resources/js/ziggy.js
import { Ziggy } from './ziggy';

// ...

route('posts.show', 1, undefined, Ziggy);
```

If you're using Vue, it can be helpful to create a global mixin so that you don't need to pass `Ziggy` in as the 4th argument every time. There is an example of how to set this up [in the docs](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#vue).

If that still doesn't work please feel free to submit an issue with a detailed explanation of your setup!

Comment: i am creating issue , FYI the detail is added to the Question .

Comment: @bakerkretzmar I keep getting a 'TypeError: this.route is not a function. 
Any tips at all?

Comment: TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function is also another error I keep getting. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @oluwatyson for the `TypeError` make sure you're making the route function available in all your Vue components with a mixin like `Vue.mixin({ methods: { route } })`. Are you using Ziggy v1? Feel free to file an issue in the repo and we can take a closer look! https://github.com/tighten/ziggy/issues

Answer (score 2):

comment or delete ziggy array on Middleware/HandleInertiaRequests.php seem like below :

```html
 public function share(Request $request)
    {
        return array_merge(parent::share($request), [
            'auth' => [
                'user' => $request->user(),
            ],
            // 'ziggy' => function () {
            //     return (new Ziggy)->toArray();
            // },
        ]);
    }
```